# Observer on Product saving for name appending

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, observers

I am creating a small module. In which I have built my own tab in System- Configuration, Name "ZARA" which consists of a textbox. I can enter words in the textbox and save the configuration.

**Question**

**Now my problem is, I want that the module should append the word entered in the configuration to the product name through an observer whenever a product is saved.**

for example, I entered "Test" as a word in the configuration. I then open a product in the backend in product management, which is called "RedShirt". When I save this now, it's called "RedShirtTest". If I save it again, it's called "RedShirtTestTest". Thank you in advance if anybody can clear my issue. I'm totally new to Magento. Please answer regarding Magento 1.9.

Comment: You've told a lot of stuff about what you want to do, but you haven't said where you are stuck. You haven't asked a question. Also, please show us your code.

Comment: I have bold out my problem, I know how I can data from configuration but now the problem is how I append that data to any product which got updated by admin? Thank you very much!

Comment: That's a statement, not a question. Please read [ask] and be very clear what your situation is, what you've been able to do, and what isn't going right (along with the code that is failing) and then we can help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).